# how to connect app engine and on premise server through VPN?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-compute-engine, firewall, vpn, service-fabric-on-premises

I need to connect Google App engine and premise server, But in this case, we must use VPN to reduce connection trouble.
[image: Expected system]

in this image show expected system.Can this system be implemented?
Please share any references or any solution to me. thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Check [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37137914/is-it-possible-to-use-google-app-engine-with-google-cloud-vpn). You can only setup [Cloud VPN](https://cloud.google.com/vpn/docs/concepts/overview) over VPC networks. GCE instances and GAE flex environment are designed to use these networks.

If you are using [GAE standard environment](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/the-appengine-environments) you would have to [forward the GAE traffic to a GCE VM](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-appengine/P2PK6g4TteY) but this is only possible via an external IP. The GCE VM would be acting as a proxy.

In any case you need a physical device on your premises.

Answer (score 0):

you can use serverless VPC access:

https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/serverless-vpc-access#use_cases

use case: Your serverless environment needs to access data from your on-premises database through Cloud VPN.