# Routing requests to GAE Flex from Cloud VPN?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-networking

I know from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37137914/is-it-possible-to-use-google-app-engine-with-google-cloud-vpn) that you can launch flex instances in a specified VPC/subnetwork and consequently make it available in a Cloud VPN, but I'm not sure what to do from there to route requests?

Is the flex instance still reachable via the *.appspot.com URL? is it accessed via internal IP? How do I make sure requests from an on-premise application is routed to my flex instance?