# Connect Google App Engine to a IPSEC Tunnel

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, routes, vpn

I'm not an expert in networking so excuse the bad wording.

I have a Google App Engine service running in Google cloud (Standard environment). I need this service to access a VPN (i.e. ip-addresses in that VPN setup). How can I set this up with an IPSEC tunnel? I've looked a bit at Google VPN but it most seems how to setup a VPN Server, I want to be the client to an external VPN network so my App Engine service can access computers on that VPN.

Thanks

Comment: App Engine Standard or Flexible? Where are you connecting to? More details are required in your question.

Comment: Standard environment, added to question.

Comment: Unless you add a VPN client within your application, AE Standard does not provide VPN features. This means using a client library to implement a VPN. Since you have provided no other details, there is no real answer yet. Google Cloud does not offer VPN features for AE Standard.

Comment: Just to be sure to understand. The VPN that you want to reach has a public IP. You have a private key (or a private certificate) for being authenticated on the VPN. Am I correct? Which is your dev language?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere This is correct. I develop the service in java (1.8)

Comment: I think you can achieve this, but you have to code all by yourselves: VPN connection establishment, and when you reach a VM through the VPN you have to route the request into the VPN manually. Lots of work! Why you can'y use Cloud VPN to establish a permanent connection and then simply forward your request trough this connection?

Comment: Please take a look at this post, I think that it would be helpful for you, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37137914/is-it-possible-to-use-google-app-engine-with-google-cloud-vpn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As other members have pointed out, there is no a direct way to connect GAE Standard service to a resource inside an external, on-premise, VPN. However, there some approaches.

There is a feature called [Serverless VPC Access](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/configure-serverless-vpc-access) that allows GAE Standard to connect to other Google Cloud resources through an internal IP, but here is the interesting part:

> Serverless VPC Access supports communication to VPC networks connected via Cloud VPN

Looking at the tutorial on [Connecting to a VPC network](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/connecting-vpc), it is mentioned something similar to what I understood you are trying to achieve:

> Your app needs to access data from your on-premises database through Cloud VPN.

The first step I would say is to connect your VPN to Cloud VPN. Since I'm not expert in those matters I'd suggest you take at its [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/vpn/docs/concepts/overview).